# Using the Blobstore API with Google Cloud Storage - http 404 error message

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

Today if an url is incorrect, users get this display from my appengine instance:

```
Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

I found this [reference](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40t%40e%40tendenci-5.1.333%40tendenci%40core%40base%40static%40jqueryupload%40server%40gae-python%40main.py/141/google.appengine.ext.webapp.blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler.send_blob/python) on how to address with a proper 404 message using the blobstore.get, but unfortunately it's not working. I figured out why. The bkey always returns some value, so it will always think "its not a invalid bkey". What I'm trying to figure out is how to write the code in the case that the bkey is invalid. Below is my code:

```
gs_filename = '/gs/%s/%s' % (settings.BUCKET, filename)
bkey = blobstore.create_gs_key(gs_filename)

if not blobstore.get(key):
   logging.info("I got a 404 error'")
else:
  return blobstore_dh.send_blob(bkey, content_type=ct)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this as well and came up with a quick workaround:

```
from google.appengine.api.blobstore import BlobNotFoundError

..

    try:
        blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key).read(1)
    except BlobNotFoundError:
        logging.info('BlobNotFoundError')
        self.abort(404)
```

Does feel a bit hackish, so if anybody finds a better way, I would love to hear about it!